# WinSock2 IPC Example

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, ipc

My task is to accept a tcp socket connection from one process and send it to another process using socket IPC mechanism of windows(according to msdn, socket, WinSock 2 to be specific, is one way to do inter-process communication on windows, maybe something like unix-domain socket, but it did not state clearly). I have searched on internet for a while and could not find any useful examples.

Can someone provide examples for setting up Winsock 2 for IPC (Inter-process communication) and duplicate/send connected tcp socket to other processes through Winsock 2 IPC? 
Or explain what is different when using Winsock 2 IPC compare to tcp socket on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: What are you referring to by "socket IPC" exactly? It sounds like what you are really looking for is to create a normal TCP listening socket that accepts an inbound connection, then creates another TCP socket to connect to another TCP server, and then passes data between the two connections in both directions. Much like any normal TCP proxy would. In which case, why not just use a real pre-made TCP proxy?

Comment: sorry, that does sounds a bit confusing, I have update the question. by socket IPC I mean use socket for inter process communication.
I need to send a connected tcp socket to another process using socket inter-process communication mechanism on windows platform.

Comment: So you want to establish a socket connection in one process and then pass the socket itself to another process so it can reuse the same connection? If so, the only way to do that is to call `WSADuplicateSocket()` in the process that owns the original socket, then pass the resulting `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure via any IPC mechanism (sockets, named pipes, mailslots, `WM_COPYDATA`, shared memory, etc) to the other process and have it then pass the structure to `WSASocket()` to create a new socket that shares the original connection.

Comment: I think you are getting confused with what IPC actually is. Sockets are just one of many different types of IPC mechanisms available for passing data between processes in general. "Socket IPC" would just be a normal socket connection established between a listening socket and a connecting/sending socket for the purpose of exchanging data between processes. Not to be confused with sharing a single socket connection between multiple processes, which is a completely different feature.

Comment: I know there are many IPC mechanisms, socket is the specific one I am asking, that is why socket is put before IPC.
by "normal socket" I guess you mean normal tcp/ip connection on localhost? And It is the only way Windows support for "socket IPC"? Then it's probably not what I want.

Comment: If all you want to do is pass data between processes using sockets, then you would simply `listen()` and `accept()` on localhost in one process, `connect()` to localhost in another process, and then use `send()` and `recv()` as needed. If you want to use TCP, that is. IOW, establish a plain ordinary TCP connection like any other. Or just use `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` if you want to use UDP instead. The fact that sockets are being used for IPC is completely irrelevant, the sockets don't care as long as you use valid IP addresses for localhost.

Comment: If that is not what you want, then you need to clarify exactly what you do want. Provide an example.